# How to push a new array and add an increment number to the object ( ID)

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I would like to find out how to I push a new Row with a unique ID.
If canvas is not empty, I would like to push a new Row with the following ID. If canvas has a Row already so next one would be 2 and so on.

Should I get the canvas array, do a filter function to search for my last row object inside with the latest ID? ( i will 1000 of row inside, so this may be slow)
Or is there a way just to increment the next number without going a loop?

```
 canvas: Array<any> = [];
 row: Array<any> = [];

    onDropSuccess(event: any, droppedOn: string) {
        if(this.canvas == [] || this.canvas == null  || this.canvas == 0 ){
            this.canvas.push(
                        new Row(1, 
                        [new Widget('Lorem ipsumrci viverra auctor')]
                        )
            );
            console.log(this.canvas)

        }else{
            this.canvas.push(
    **//How to push here a new row with unique ID**
                        new Row(1, 
                        [new Widget('Lorem ipsumrci viverra auctor')]
                        )
            );
            console.log(this.canvas)


        }


    }

    class Row {
        constructor(public id: Number, public widgets: Array<Widget>) {}
    }
    class Widget {
        constructor(public name: string) {}
    }
```

Comment: new Row(this.canvas.length + 1, ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your rows always start at 1 and just need to be incremented to be unique, all you need is (no conditionals necessary since your array starts at a length of 0 anyways):

```
onDropSuccess(event: any, droppedOn: string) {
  this.canvas.push(
    new Row(this.canvas.length+1, [new Widget('Lorem ipsumrci viverra auctor')])
  );
}
```

If your array may have any possible set of number id's in any order, you can sort the array, find the highest number, and then increment:

```
onDropSuccess(event: any, droppedOn: string) {
  let highestId = this.canvas.slice()
    .sort((a, b) => a.id-b.id)[this.canvas.length-1].id;

  this.canvas.push(
    new Row(highestId+1, [new Widget('Lorem ipsumrci viverra auctor')])
  );
}
```